# Pinch zoom anywhere

Tags: android, zooming, pinch

Is it possible in Android to implement app/service which gives an ability of pinch zoom anywhere/anytime for example zoom desktop like magnifier in Windows? It would be useful, because not all applications supports pinch zoom e.g., gmail. I didn't find such app on https://play.google.com, so is it impossible to implement?
I saw that feature on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

No it aint, it would violate the security in the android OS, you only have the scope of your application.
else you have to make a root mod, which needs to be flashed onto your phone